# How much does continuity correction improve the normal approximation of binomial?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

From the central limit theorem, we know that $(\text{Bin}(n,p)-np)/\sqrt{npq}$ is approximately normal, with $q=1-p$. The Berry-Esseen theorem gives an upper bound for the error of this approximation: 
$$
\sup_{x\in \mathbb R}\left|\mathbb P\left(\frac{\text{Bin}(n,p)-np}{\sqrt{npq}}\le x\right)-\Phi(x)\right|\le \frac{C(p^2+q^2)}{\sqrt{npq}}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{npq}}\tag{$*$}
$$
Furthermore, this estimate is optimal up to a constant, because the largest point probability for $\text{Bin}(n,p)$ is on the order of $1/\sqrt{2\pi npq}$.

However, it is common practice to use a "continutity correction" when approximating a binomial distribtuion by a normal. I was wondering whether this correction leads to significant improvements in the error. That is, are there any convenient upper bounds for 
$$
\sup_{k\in \mathbb Z} \left|\mathbb P\left(\text{Bin}(n,p)\le k\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{k+\frac12-np}{\sqrt{npq}}\right)\right|
$$
which are better than ($*$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\Bin{\text{Bin}}$Ok, I found the answer. Except in the case $p=1/2$, the continuity correction is not enough to improve the Berry-Esseen bound.

Precisely, letting $F(k)=P(\Bin(n,p)\le k)$, and $z=(k+\frac12-np)/\sqrt{np(1-p)}$, and letting $\phi(z)$ be the pdf of the standard normal, then
$$
F(k) = \Phi(z) +\frac{p-q}{6\sqrt{npq}}(z^2-1)\phi(z)+O(1/n)
$$
Only when $p=q$ does the $1/\sqrt{n}$ term disappear.

Comment: What about the effect when comparing a difference of two values of the CDF, especially close ones? For example, we might compare the corrected and uncorrected approximations to $P(Bin(n,p) \in [np-\sqrt{npq},np+\sqrt{npq}])$.

Comment: @Ian For the probability of an interval, the worst case error is on the order of $1/\sqrt{n}$ for both cases, but I haven't though about how much the constant improves when the correction is incorporated.

Comment: Sure that's true of the absolute error, but what about relative error? Certainly the relative error is dramatically improved if the interval in question only contains 1 integer.

Comment: Good question, one that I also have not thought about. I think your questions diverge from mine enough that they would warrant asking a separate question.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Do you have reference for a constant in the $O(1/n)$?

Comment: @RussLyons See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgeworth_series#The_Edgeworth_series. You want the $\frac1n$ term of the last equation in that section. $\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_4$ are respectively the standardized skewness and kurtosis of a Bernoulli($p$) random variable.

Comment: @MikeEarnest The link you give is for densities, but it gives a reference [6] https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176347637 for lattice distributions. In any case, neither one provides what I am asking for, which is not an asymptotic expansion, but an actual bound on the error. I would be happy even with a bound that holds for large $n$, but how large should be specified.